# Como iterar array PHP recebida como JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, array, mongodb

Tenho o seguinte `JSON`, que crio pelo método `JSON.stringify(dados`), e passo via `ajax` para o `php`:

```
{"nome":"nome_da_pessoa", "registro":"registro_da_pessoa", "departamento":"_$oid/5aac50..."}
```

Quando recebo no PHP, faço a conversão pelo `json_decode($_POST['dado']);`.

Gostaria de iterar este array, e quando encontrar o valor _$oid/, separasse e atualizasse o item somente com a parte depois da /.
Por exemplo: `dado[departamento] = "5aac50..."`

Seguem os códigos que não estão funcionando.

Código Js:

```
var dados = {};
    $("form input").each(function () {
        var campo = $(this).attr("name"), valor = $(this).val();
        dados[campo] = valor;
    });
    $("form select").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("carrega") == "s") {
            var campo = $(this).attr("name"), valor = "_$oid/" + $(this).val();
            dados[campo] = valor;
        } else {
            var campo = $(this).attr("name"), valor = $(this).val();
            dados[campo] = valor;
        }
    });
    dados["excluido"] = "n";
    dados["logado"] = "n";
    var dado = JSON.stringify(dados);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'funcoes/registros.php',
        data: {
            "funcao": "incluidado",
            "collection": collection,
            "dado": dado
        },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },
        success: function (dados) {
            preenchetabela(collection);
        }
    });
```

Código PHP:

```
$collection = $_POST['collection'];
        $dado = json_decode($_POST['dado']);

        // CONSEGUIR ALTERAR O $oid_
        foreach ($dado as $key => $value) {
            $procura = '_$oid/';
            if (strripos($value, $procura) === false) {
                // não altera nada
            } else {
                // remove o _$oid do valor
                $tags = explode($procura, $value);
                $dado[$key] = $tags[1];
            }
        }

        try {
            $insert = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite; // Monta o BulkWrite
            $insert->insert($dado);
            $conexao->executeBulkWrite($bd . "usuarios", $insert);
            echo json_encode("Registro realizado com sucesso!");
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
        }
```

Comment: Isso não está claro, muito código mas não vai direto ao ponto. Quall a dúvida na verdade?

Comment: Desculpem a falta de clareza. De fato fica difícil explicar tudo.
A minha intenção é criar uma biblioteca JS que permita seguir padrões para a criação de formulários, sem precisar ficar desenvolvendo uma função para cada formulário.
Estou varrendo os padrões e quando acho um campo select que foi populado com resultados de uma collection, eu acrescendo o _$oid/ antes de seu _id para poder transformar em ObjectId e referenciá-lo em coutra collection.
Não sei se ficou claro, mas o código funcionou conforme as alterações que comentei na resposta abaixo.
Vlw pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primeiramente. O formato dos dados que você colocou na pergunta não é um `Array`, e sim um `Objeto`. Um array `JSON` possui `[]` delimitando seu conteúdo. Um objeto possui `{}`.

Não conheço a estrutura do `objeto` json que você está passando para seu código PHP, no entanto creio que a maneira que você está buscando o valor para substituir seja pouco intuitivo, por se tratar de uma estrutura com 'chaves' e 'valores'. Você poderia simplesmente buscar pela chave desejada, ou, conhecendo a estrutura, poderia simplesmente alterar o valor da chave diretamente, sabendo que ela deve existir de antemão.

Segue um exemplo de código que altera o valor do campo 'departamento' para manter o valor após a '/' delimitadora.

```
$json = json_decode('{"nome":"nome_da_pessoa", "registro":"registro_da_pessoa", "departamento":"_$oid/5aac50..."}');

// Percorrendo os campos do objeto (desnecessário..)
// foreach($json as $k => $v) {
//   if($k === 'departamento') {
//     echo("achou..");
//     $json->{$k} = explode("/", $v)[1];
//     break;
//   }
// }

// Acessando diretamente o campo (poderia verificar a existencia antes..)
$json->departamento = explode('/', $json->departamento)[1];

foreach($json as $k=>$v) {
  echo($k . " = " . $v . "\n");
}
```

Comment: Na realidade, eu estou criado uma biblioteca de funções em Js para facilitar a criação dos formulários. Assim, não pretendo referenciar diretamente o campo: $json->departamento.
Mas sua resposta foi válida porque eu estava referenciando errado: $dado[$key] = $tags[1];
Agora estou referenciando conforme você mostrou:
foreach ($dado as $key => $value) {
            $procura = '_$oid/';
            if (strripos($value, $procura) === false) {
                // Não faz nada
            } else {
                $dado->$key = explode('/', $dado->$key)[1];
            }
        }

Comment: Ok então, bom poder ajudar em alguma coisa.